# imageview seems to be invisible

Tags: java, android, xml, image

i got a problem with imageView not displaying my image in android studio.
The image is displayed in layout editor but when i launch the emulator the imageView act just like if i had set the visibility on " invisible" : the image is not appearing but it still take up the space of my imageview.

imaview 16 at the end of the xml.
Xml :

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/etape_1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="left">


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAcc"
                    android:background="@drawable/home"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Accueil"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="21sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/black"
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp" />

        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:breakStrategy="simple"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:id="@+id/radio3"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:id="@+id/radio4"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:id="@+id/radio5"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </ViewFlipper>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:text="Valider"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/home"
                android:id="@+id/imaView16"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- i tried with different image size and with Jpeg/Png it doesn't work either.
- none of imageview seems to works on this layout and i cant find why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app:srcCompat` is generally used for vector type drawable. If you are are using vector drawable make sure the vector drawable color is different from the background color. Also re-check the below things,

**A**. Increase the `layout_height` of you ImageView (The current dp might be too small to display the image)

**B**. for non-vector drawable use `android:src` with a solid background in `android:background` just to make sure the image is showing.

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageView you must use `android:src` not `app:srcCompat`, So:

Change this:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/black"
```

With this:

```
android:src="@drawable/black"
```

Answer (score 0):

change `app:srcCompat="@drawable/black"` to `android:background="@drawable/black"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to rename the image without any special characters.

Comment: Hi Sartaj. Thanks for your answer. But we need more than Arnold Schwarzenegger style 1 liners! What characters are not allowed? Links to documentation? Please take the time to craft a good answer. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Cheers!